# Can't store OVH credentials in Terraform .tfvars file

Tags: terraform, ovh

I'm looking for some guidance and help. I'm new with terraform and trying new things. I added OVH provider for DNS records, but I'm having troubles with passing credentials.

I was trying to pass OVH credentials as variables and store them in credentials.tfvars or credentials.auto.tfvars files, but I'm getting 403 Forbidden errors when using terraform plan.

Next I placed all credentials in main.tf file and everything works ok. I'm looking for some guidance what can be wrong with my config.

Here are example files for my terraform.

main.tf

```
terraform { 
  required_providers { 
    docker = { 
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker" 
      version = "3.0.2" 
    } 
    ovh = { 
      source = "ovh/ovh" 
      version = "0.32.0" 
    } 
  } 
} 

variable "ovhapplication_key" { 
  type = string 
} 

variable "ovhapplication_secret" { 
  type = string 
} 
    
variable "ovhconsumer_key" { 
  type = string 
} 

variable "MariaDBPass" { 
  type = string 
} 
    
variable "Pass" { 
  type = string 
} 

provider "docker" { 
  host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock" 
} 
    
provider "ovh" { 
  endpoint           = "ovh-eu" 
  application_key    = "var.ovhapplication_key" 
  application_secret = "var.ovhapplication_secret" 
  consumer_key       = "var.ovhconsumer_key" 
}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
ovhapplication_key="SomeCredentials" 
ovhapplication_secret="SomeCredentials"  
ovhconsumer_key="SomeCredentials" 
MariaDBPass="SomeCredentials" 
Pass="SomeCredentials"
```

Comment: Guessing here:  maybe take the quotes off of the var names when you reference them in the provider block?  EG `application_secret = var.ovhapplication_secret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a couple of problems with the code you have posted. First problem seems to be the way you are trying to [reference the variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#using-input-variable-values). The way your code shows it, what happens is that variables are not substituted for values. You will get string literals. In other words, this:

```
application_key    = "var.ovhapplication_key" 
application_secret = "var.ovhapplication_secret" 
consumer_key       = "var.ovhconsumer_key"
```

will tell terraform to read the application key the same way it is written, i.e., `"var.ovhapplication_key"`. To fix this, you need to fix variable references to use the correct syntax:

```
application_key    = var.ovhapplication_key
application_secret = var.ovhapplication_secret
consumer_key       = var.ovhconsumer_key
```

The second problem could be the naming convention of your tfvars files. Terraform should pick up auotmagically all the `*.auto.tfvars` files. So you might have set the variable values in a properly named file, but the way you were referencing them in the `provider` block is still using string literals. The second option you mentioned for the file name, i.e., `credentials.tfvars` would mean you need to specify that file name when calling different terraform commands, e.g:

```
terraform plan -var-file="credentials.tfvars"
```

Note that terraform picks up any variables defined in `terraform.tfvars` automatically. Make sure you go through the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) as well.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking about yesterday  Of course I was placing values instead of references. Thanks for your help!